# React component should throw undefined error, but it didn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Steps to reproduce**

Currently I'm working on a react native project, and one of my components looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Box, Text, RowBox, Card, CardTitle } from '../../../component';
import { Colors, Size } from '../../../config';
import Echarts from 'native-echarts';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class HistoryBuy extends React.PureComponent {

  render () {
    console.log('0', this.props.history);
    const { abnormal } = this.props.history;
    console.log('1', this.props.history);
    const option = abnormal.amount;
    console.log('2', this.props.history);
    return (
      <Card title="SOME TITLE">
        <Box style={{ height: Size.px(560) }} padding={Size.px(30)}>
          <Echarts option={option} height={Size.px(500)} width={Size.DEVICE_WIDTH - Size.px(60)}/>
        </Box>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  history: state.purchase.history,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HistoryBuy);
```

The only prop `history` it use was stored in redux with initial state:

```
history: {
    abnormal: {
      amount: [],
      count: []
    },
    normal: {
      amount: [],
      count: []
    },
    time: []
  }
```

And suddenly I change `history` to `{}`

**What is expected?**

Throw undefined error. Because `this.props.history` changes to `{}`, `this.props.history.abnormal` is undefined, so `const option = abnormal.amount;` should throw an error.

**What happened?**

It does not throw an error, just print console in chrome.

Besides, it console 5 times, not 6 times, and seems that everything after `const option = abnormal.amount;` is unreachable.
[image]

**version**

- "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
- "react-native": "0.48.2"

Comment: You're changing your `history` object manually in your reducer?

Comment: @Kox No, I changed `history` with an action and dispatch that action.

Comment: interesting.. I believe you are not mutating your state and your reducer ends with something like: `return { ...state, state.purchase.history: {} }` ?

Comment: @Kox what I write in reducer is: ```case HISTORY:
    console.log(action);
    return { ...state, history: action.data };```, and in the console it print `data:{}, type:"p/HISTORY"`

Comment: right. Everything looks good here. I would advise you to place a `debugger` in your reducer and in your render function to inspect this in more depth. Cannot do a lot with just this piece of code.

Comment: @Kox Thank u for ur time, really appreciate it.

Comment: let me know when you find the  answer!